# Append hyperlink at the first of a div

Tags: jquery, append

I have following code to show post details in single page. I would like to move link to following `post-info` div using jQuery by span class `first-tag`. How can I achieve?

```
<a href="#">
<span class="first-tag">gaming</span>
</a>
```

`<div class="post-info"> " | " <span>Title </span></div>`

Link will append inside post-info div but before the span tag. Like as follows-

```
<div class="post-info">
<a href="#">
<span class="first-tag">gaming</span>
</a>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
</div>
```

Please, check the [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aynamohol/BVF9N/10/embedded/result/)

Comment: *scratches head. I wrote 4 examples, and kept rereading the question and got confused...* **Please supply some sort of additional info**

Comment: IS the goal as this: `find` a `link` with a specific `class`, and `append, or prepend` that `a` to specific `div`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
jQuery(".first-tag").parent("a").addClass("a");

jQuery(".a").prependTo(".post-info");
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding of your question, you need to use `prependTo()`

```
jQuery(".pppp").prependTo(".post-info");
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/laraprabhu/BVF9N/12/)